# Express is not serving to second API while processing the first API

Tags: node.js, express

I am testing my API server. I want to know why express is not serving the second API request while processing the first API request.

I have created test routes.
My first route `/sleep` processing a request with a timer of 10 seconds.

Second route `/test` is simply response with a message.

```
app.get('/sleep', function (req, res) {
   let newTime = (new Date()).getTime() + 10 * 1000;
   let x = 1;
   while (x) {
      let currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
      x = newTime < currTime ? 0 : 1;
   }
   return res.send("One minute complete");
});

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   return res.send("One minute test");
});
```

I have hit the `/sleep` route from browser and in new tab hit the `/test`.
the second route is responding after the first route competition.

So why is this happening. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs is "single threaded". You should not block the thread.

If you want to delay response just use [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args)

```
app.get('/sleep', function (req, res) {
   setTimeout(function() { res.send('10 seconds complete'); }, 10*1000)
});

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   return res.send("One minute test");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Yury,
But i was not intend to wait the request. 
I am trying to test why it is not serving the second request while processing the first.

Comment: @NishikantTyagi As I've written nodejs is "single threaded". Your code blocks the only thread available to user that is why. Your approach simply goes against nodejs programming model: asynchronous code and event loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is, Node is single threaded and your synchronous code(which is given below) creating a blocker for it.

```
let newTime = (new Date()).getTime() + 10 * 1000;
  let x = 1;
  while (x) {
    let currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    x = newTime < currTime ? 0 : 1;
  }
```

**Solution:** Make it asynchronous, so it will be sent to event loop.

**Example:** Instead of using this synchronous logic, use `setTimeout`

`setTimeout(function() { res.send('done'); }, 10000)`